# how to remove duplicated strings and merge all columns strings in one?

Tags: r

I have a data looks like the following df

```
df<- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("DNAJC11;FGOTG", 
"MAPK14", "PPIB", "RBX1", "USP14"), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(c(4L, 
3L, 2L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("", "DNAJC9", "MAPK14", "USP14"), class = "factor"), 
    V3 = structure(c(3L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 1L), .Label = c("", "DNAJC11;FGOTG", 
    "GCLC", "GSR", "STIP1"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("V1", 
"V2", "V3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

I want to merge all columns into one and then keep the unique ones 
for example the output should look like this

```
USP14
DNAJC11;FGOTG
MAPK14
PPIB
RBX1
DNAJC9
GCLC
GSR
STIP1
```

I tried to use `melt`function but I could not figure out how to do this, any comment is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: `unlist` then `unique` ?

Comment: @rawr thanks for your reply, if you don't mind, please make an answer but if it is not worth it then don't worry I will try to use the unlist function. once again thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
unique(as.vector(as.matrix(df)))
```

To remove the entries with no characters:

```
vec<-unique(as.vector(as.matrix(df)))
vec[-which(vec=="")]
```

or, courtesy @rawr

```
Filter(nzchar, unique(as.vector(as.matrix(df))))
```

Comment: or `Filter(nzchar, unique(as.vector(as.matrix(df))))` to remove no characters